# Responding in MQTT with Python

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm having a little bit of a delay-issue in my MQTT Python (v2.7) script that has me wondering...

So I have one device request a function to another device. Let's call them A and B.

So A sends out a MQTT message to do something, and B does that function. I have A send it out by a normal publish method. There are no issues here.

B gets the published message with the part:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    if msg.topic == "action":
            >> then do something here <<
```

Also there seem to be no issues here. It gets the message and it performs the action.

The problem gets here when I try to report back what it's going, which looks like this:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    if msg.topic == "action":
            >> then do something here <<
            client.publish("report", payload=message1, qos=2, retain=False)
            >> then do some more action here <<
            client.publish("report", payload=message2, qos=2, retain=False)
```

The problem is not that it doesn't do the action nor that it doesnt do the action, but it seems that it will do both, but rather in a very strange order, like:

```
action
action
(several seconds wait)
message1
message2
```

This doesn't seem right? How can I make the script send out the message before it's doing the second part?

Comment: Where do you observe that it "sends all the messages"? By receiving on device A?

Comment: I'm using mosquitto_sub to subscribe to all topics and see what comes in.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as expected.

The network loop is a single thread which is already handling the incoming message. The publishes are queued up until the `on_message` function completes and then the network loop will handle these queued publishes

Comment: Is there a way to make it work regardlessly? Surely there must be a solution to this.

Comment: Not with a single instance of the MQTT client

Answer (score 1):

TCP stack is asynchronous. When you call for sending data, it does not mean that it goes out immediately. There is an event loop running behind your code. If you want to do something in sequence, you must break your sequential tasks into separate functions and call them on next `on_publish()` when the message was really sent out.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to send out messages using the library:

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as mqttc
```

and using a:

```
mqttc.single("report", payload=message1, qos=2, hostname=XXXX, port=XXXX)
```

which will follow the natural flow of the script and still send out the message.

Comment: That is effectively running 2 separate MQTT clients

Comment: @hardillb I was a little confused. I do understand what you mean now, though. Yes, it is. Thanks for getting me on the right path!